# Does a paid Chrome extension need to request the identity permission to offer a free trial?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

per [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#offering-free-trial) it seems I need to request the identity permission in order to offer a free trial in a paid extension.

Is there any way around this? I do not need to have access to the user's email for this extension, and since it operates with a social media platform, requesting that permission might be seen as intrusive.

It'd be great if I could somehow verify the license key without needing to have access to the user's email or identity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/identify_user#when), using Google's identity is required if you use Chrome Web Store Payment System.

If you don't want to use Google's identity, you would have to implement a different Custom payment solution.